# Improving the implementation of a plugin architecture

Tags: javascript

I have an extend method included in my library, making it possible for methods to be added to the core library:

```
library.prototype.extend = function(name,plugin) {

    library.prototype[name] = plugin.init;

    for (var method in plugin) {

        if(method !== 'init') {

            library.prototype[name].prototype[method] = plugin[method]; 

        }

    }

};
```

In use it looks like so:

```
library.prototype.extend('aReallyInterestingPlugin', {

    //the init method gets added to the base libraries prototype
    init: function() {

        this.shouldBePrivate;

    },

    //another other methods are created as a prototype of the newly added Plugin
    anotherMethod : function() {
        //this should have access to the shouldBePrivate var
    }
});
```

Users are then able to call the plugin like so:

```
var test = new library();
test.aReallyInterestingPlugin();
```

This works but I'm not exactly happy with the approach and have been trying to find an alternative pattern to make this work.

The problem with it, is that the init and the anotherMethod are added directly to the libraries prototype chain so their scope is also the global libraries scope which is messy because if any instance variables are declared (like shouldBePrivate above) they are also added to the libraries prototype chain.

How can I enable the plugin to be added and have it's own private scope? One way I've thought of is that a plugin could always be called as a constructor (and will therefore have it's own scope and this context) but then I'm not sure how clean that is...for instance for that to work the user would have to do something like this when calling the plugin:

```
var test = new library();
test.aPlugin = new aReallyInterestingPlugin();
```

Comment: do you allow several instances of Library ?

Comment: And do you want your plugin to act like a singleton i.e. 'shouldbePrivate' should be private... to the plugin (whatever Library it's being used with) or to the plugin AND to the library instance ?

Comment: Yes, 'shouldBePrivate' should only be accessible within the plugin.

Comment: mmm maybe you'll see what i mean in my reply, but i mean : if lib1 = new Library(); lib2=new Library(), then should we have lib1.somePlugin === lib2.somePlugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to have the plugin method bound to a new object, so that they don't 'pollute' the Library.
But instead of having the plugin as a method of a Library instance, have it rather as a lazy getter, so the syntax is more fluid, and you can build a new instance only if required.
The plugin syntax could then be simplified : just use a javascript class => a function that has methods defined on its prototype.
I think also that it makes sense to have 'extend' as a property of Library, not a method set on its prototype, since no instance should make use of it.

With this you can add a plugin with

```
library.extend('aReallyInterestingPlugin',AReallyInterestingPluginClass);
```

to use you can write

```
var myLibrary = new Library();

myLibrary.somePlugin.someMethod(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

The code would look like :

```
library.extend = function(name,plugin) {    
    var pluginInstance = null; // lazy evaluation to avoid useless memory consumption

    var pluginGetter = function() {
       if (pluginInstance == null) pluginInstance = new plugin();
       return pluginInstance;                                       };

    Object.defineProperty( Library.prototype, name, 
                                       { get: pluginGetter, enumerable : true } ); 
} ;
```

A plugin is just standard javascript class:

```
 function MyPlugin() {
      this.pluginProperty1 = 'some value';
 }

 MyPlugin.prototype = {
      method1 : function() { /* do things */} ,
      method2 : function() { /* do other things */ }
 };
```

Notice that with this scheme the plugin is a singleton, i.e. every instances of Library will return the same object when asked for the same plugin.

If you prefer once plugin instance per Library, just have the Library constructor hold the plugins instances. (maybe in a hidden property).

```
function Library() {
    // the code allready here...        
    var pluginInstances = {};
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'pluginInstances', 
                  { get : function() { return pluginInstances }, enumerable : false });
}

library.extend = function(name,plugin) {        
    var pluginGetter = function() {
       if (! this.pluginInstances[name] ) this.pluginInstances[name] = new plugin();
       return this.pluginInstances[name];
    };

    Object.defineProperty( Library.prototype, name, 
                                       { get: pluginGetter, enumerable : true } );    
} ;
```

syntax for the plugin and for the use remains the same.

Edit : for older Browser support, you can still use a function instead of a getter :

```
function Library() {
    // the code allready here...        
    this.pluginInstances= {} ;
}

library.extend = function(name,plugin) {        
    Library.prototype[name] = function() {
       if (! this.pluginInstances[name] ) this.pluginInstances[name] = new plugin();
       return this.pluginInstances[name];
    };    
} ;
```

to use it you would do :

```
var myLibrary = new Library();

myLibrary.somePlugin().someMethod(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Edit 2 : version with singleton plugins and with *no* getters is :

```
 function Library() {        /* same code */    }

library.extend = function(name,plugin)    {     
    var pluginInstance = null; // lazy evaluation to avoid useless memory consumption    
    Library.prototype[name] = function() {
       if (pluginInstance == null) pluginInstance = new plugin();
       return pluginInstance;                                       };
}
```

Comment: This is really interesting approach but I'm not sure I can get away with the ECMA stuff as we're still supporting IE7. Learnt some from this though.

Comment: Good point on having the extend method as a property of the library rather than a method on the prototype chain.

Comment: @MikeRifgin : you're welcome. See my edit, with a small change we can have it work on older Browsers (didn't know that was a requirement). The syntax is still easy, and a plugin is just a simple standard Javascript class, which is way better than any convention imho.

Comment: Aha, I see. I think though the module pattern creates a cleaner approach for anyone writing a plugin so I'm going to try and work that in to my library and see how it works. If not I might come back to this approach

Comment: Notice that the other solution uses the 'new' operator, and yet returns another object, confusing the ways one creates object in js. Notice also that you can only add a plugin to a Lib instance, that other instances won't see, which is just useless. The 'benefit' of it is only complexity. The solutionS i suggest just require a constructor function, and allows to choose wether you want the plugins to be singletons or not. With less lines of code, and no special convention to explain to your users -just provide a Class-. But you're free to choose the wrong way !! ;-)

Comment: Ah, see what you mean about the plugin only getting added to the instance. If I were to use your approach I think I''d want a singleton every time....I'd need the same plugin to be returned but with the option of throwing different parameters at it

Comment: Just playing with this now. How do i Get access to the library context from within a plugin? In this fiddle I'm trying to access a property called test in the plugin but it's undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/skQML/

Comment: 1) I think that you want to use my edit 2 (singleton + method) and not edit 1 (own plugin instances + method). 2) Let me know if you want Library to be a singleton (i would quite bet that you do).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/skQML/1/ I can't get to the test property of the library. I'm not sure if I want a singleton for the library or not. The library will be instantiated multiple times and fed in different parameters so I'm not sure I do need it to be a singleton.

Comment: @MikeRifgin : in this case, register the plugins, and instantiate them in Library's constructor, where you'll notify them of their host library :  http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/skQML/2/

Comment: That's great, thanks. Do I really need to do all the checking in the extend method though? http://jsfiddle.net/skQML/3. I think I can make the assumption that a user won't try to add a plugin more than once? This code still seems to work....http://jsfiddle.net/skQML/3/ any drawbacks?

Comment: You're welcome. Question is : defensive programming or not ? My take is that those checks do not affect performances (only when registering), and it might prevent headaches in complex projects. Imho, it It makes sense to be very defensive(check everything, even more than i did) in early dev stages, and remove most defensive code when all seems neat... It's up to you !

Comment: One other issue with this which is a game breaker is that the plugin is instantiated as soon as the Library is instantiated. So in this fiddle the console.log in the plugin is fired when I'm not even calling the plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/skQML/4/ . I think I need to find another way to achieve this

Comment: How could you seriously doubt i'd settle this  point ? ;-) So since you really needed lazy instantiation, this fiddle does just that  :  http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/skQML/5/  Btw i sell my services as consultant for javascript issues if you search for this kind of help with a guarantee on results and response time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42987/discussion-between-mike-rifgin-and-gamealchemist)

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question. There was a blog post about prototype-liked development and the fact that a lot of people are avoiding it. I'll go with something like this:

```
var Library = function() {
    var api;
    var private = "some value";
    var privateMethod = function() {
        console.log(private);
    }
    var registerPlugin = function(name, plugin) {
        api[name] = plugin.call(api);
    }
    var publicMethod = function() {
        privateMethod();
    }
    return api = {
        show: publicMethod,
        plugin: registerPlugin
    }
}

// usage of the library
var library = new Library();
library.show();

// registering a plugin
library.plugin("awesome", function() {
    var api, library = this;
    var pluginVar = "That's a plugin";
    var pluginMethod = function() {
        console.log(pluginVar);
        library.show();
    }
    return api = {
        gogo: pluginMethod
    }
});

// calling a method of the plugin
library.awesome.gogo();
```

The library is just a function which has its own scope, its own private and public methods and exports an API. The plugin is actually another function with the same capabilities, but it is invoked with the library's API as a scope. So, all the public methods of the library are available and you are able to use them. And of course you keep the privacy of the plugin. I'll suggest to read about [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). I personally use it alot. It really saves me a lot of problems.

P.S.
Here is a jsfiddle using the code above http://jsfiddle.net/XyTJF/

Comment: That definitely looks like a possible solution. I had considered the module pattern but had thought of a good way to tie the module to the base library